# Wamp database doesn't update all fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am inserting data in my WAMP database from user input:

**PHP**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","beni","2155","visitbulgaria");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$forename = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Forename']);
$surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Surname']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Email']);
$username  = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con,$_POST['Username']);
$password  = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con,$_POST['Password']);

$sql="INSERT INTO `customer`(`Forename`, `Surname`, `Email`, `Username`, `Password`)
VALUES ('$forename', '$surname', '$email', '$username', '$password')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="insert.php" method="post">
            Firstname: <input type="text" name="Forename">
            Lastname: <input type="text" name="Surname">
            Email: <input type="text" name="Email">
            username: <input type="text" name="Username">
            pass: <input type="text" name="Password">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

whah happens here is that on submit it does work but when I look at the database in *phpMyAdmin* it has only added the first three record (`forename`, `surname` and `email` and then the `username` and `password` field are left blank, and I have no idea how to fix that and why it is doing it.

Comment: when you are firing your query?? I mean `mysqli_query()`..

Comment: could you pls post your table-schema

Comment: pls change $username', '$password' to direct values and check does it work...like 'testusername','testpassword'

Comment: make sure ` is character pasting problem and in actual code it is ' for `

Comment: when i change them to direct values it does work, but I still do not understand the problem.

Comment: Try putting this line before you do the mysqli escaping. `var_dump($_POST); die(); ` This will verify that all fields are being POSTed correctly to your script

Comment: Perhaps the size of the configured fields in the database. What type and size of field for username and password?

Comment: at this point I made all fields text untill i figure out what the problem is

Comment: As @LucasHenrique suggested, what are the field sizes for username and password, and how long are the strings that you are trying to insert into the username and password fields. What were the results of `var_dump($_POST); die();` ? Without this information, we are not going to be able to help you

Comment: This is the result of var_dump: array (size=3)
  'Forename' => string 'Albena' (length=6)
  'Surname' => string 'dfsf' (length=4)
  'Email' => string 'sfdfasdqi' (length=9)   and the field are text with no size set (as all other filed in my db) and i'm passing no more than 5 characters.

Comment: And what type and size of field for username and password in BD?

Comment: There is the problem, the username and password fields are not POSTing. Based on the code you pasted here, that is not possible. There must be something else interfering with this that we have not seen yet.

Comment: @LucasHenrique, if it is a field of type `text`, there is no size set. Just took a minute to figure out that's what user2567538 was trying to say